# How to remove Twitter Responsive Bootstrap margin?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first time trying out twitter bootstrap and css grids.

I used the Basic Marketing Site as my sample html markup and added another header/logo box at the top of `.hero-unit` class outside the `div.container` because i want to able to use 100% width of the page on all sizes.

This is my header logo markups.

```
<header id="logo" class="logo-box">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

How would i remove the margin from top,left,right of the black box? I use the bootstrap-responsive.css by the way. Should i just make a new rules for the new markups or is there a span or row class where i can just include the logo markups and style that span/row from the bootstrap.css.

The image link will show the logo box and the margins that i want to remove.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be5lS.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the image in the background? Like it has been used here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ for the `jumbotron` class.

`background: linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);` You can of-course have your image here instead. I'd post more of my code here though. Use chrome devtools to learn more from bootstrap's homepage.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get your answer but are you suggesting to just use an image instead of backounrd-color property? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how your `logo` id and `logo-container` is set up right now, style wise. It'd be helpful if you put your css properties online. I am suggesting to look at the code for the bootstrap's home page and replicate it for your site.